# iOS show more views from xib inside view

Tags: ios, view, xib, subview

I am working on the iOS app but I need help with showing more custom views from xib files inside one view.

What I need is something like this:

[image: Layout]

You can see one root view, some labels and 3 custom subviews. Each subview has its own xid file but I don't know how to show them one next to each other.

I put there three views in interface builder and I thought that I just create three UIView outlets and I initialize them with loadNibName method but it doesn't work. Here is a code from controller:

```
@interface ViewController_iPad () {

   __strong IBOutlet UIView *view1;
   __strong IBOutlet UIView *view2;
   __strong IBOutlet UIView *view3;
}

@end



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
   view1 = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];

   nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView2" owner:self options:nil];
   view2 = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];

   nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView3" owner:self options:nil];
   view3 = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];

 }
```

With this code subviews are empty and contain from xib files doesn't show.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Or if is it a good way how to do that? Should I use some container instead subviews? Than you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
[view1 addSubview:[nibContents objectAtIndex:0]];
```

in place of

```
view1 = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibility as fa as i know 1. Where do you add you sub views to main view 2. In ->Target -> Build Phase ->
 your xib files are included